# Exception shared SQL variable in Flutter for two different navatigationrail

Tags: sql, flutter

I get an exception from this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'visualization.dart';
import 'personalization.dart';
import 'milestones.dart';
import 'newdata.dart';

// import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
// import 'package:path/path.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  sqfliteFfiInit();
  databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class DatabaseHelper {
  static Database? _database;
  static const String tableName = 'baby_data';

  static Future<void> initialize() async {
    _database = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'baby_tracker.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
          '''
          CREATE TABLE $tableName(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            weight REAL,
            height REAL,
            timestamp TEXT
          )
          ''',
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> insertData(double weight, double height) async {
    if (_database != null) {
      await _database!.insert(
        tableName,
        {
          'weight': weight,
          'height': height,
          'timestamp': DateTime.now().toLocal().toString(),
        },
      );
    }
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryData() async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return await _database!.query(
        tableName,
        orderBy: 'timestamp DESC',
      );
    }
    return [];
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Baby Tracker',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: BabyTrackerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class BabyTrackerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BabyTrackerScreenState createState() => _BabyTrackerScreenState();
}

class _BabyTrackerScreenState extends State<BabyTrackerScreen> {
  double weight = 0.0;
  double height = 0.0;

  void _onWeightChanged(double newValue) {
    setState(() {
      weight = newValue;
    });
  }

  void _onHeightChanged(double newValue) {
    setState(() {
      height = newValue;
    });
  }

  void _onAddData() {
    DatabaseHelper.insertData(weight, height);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DatabaseHelper.initialize();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Baby Tracker'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Enter Weight and Height',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Weight (kg)'),
                    Slider(
                      value: weight,
                      onChanged: _onWeightChanged,
                      min: 0,
                      max: 20,
                      divisions: 40,
                    ),
                    Text(weight.toStringAsFixed(2)),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 16),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Height (cm)'),
                    Slider(
                      value: height,
                      onChanged: _onHeightChanged,
                      min: 0,
                      max: 150,
                      divisions: 150,
                    ),
                    Text(height.toStringAsFixed(2)),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _onAddData,
              child: Text('Add Data'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Exception:

> SqfliteFfiException (SqfliteFfiException(sqlite_error: 1, , SqliteException(1): while preparing statement, no such table: baby_data, SQL logic error (code 1)
> Causing statement: INSERT INTO baby_data (weight, height, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)}) DatabaseException(SqliteException(1): while preparing statement, no such table: baby_data, SQL logic error (code 1)
> Causing statement: INSERT INTO baby_data (weight, height, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)) sql 'INSERT INTO baby_data (weight, height, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' args [10.5, 0.0, 2023-10-03 19:57:40.697649] {details: {database: {path: /home/michael/dev/track_the_baby/.dart_tool/sqflite_common_ffi/databases/baby_tracker.db, id: 1, readOnly: false, singleInstance: true}}})